# type's behavior with weakref - can't understand

Tags: python, cpython

I always believed that in Python interpreter values of `x.__class__` and `type(x)` are equivalent. But if we do the following (in Python 2.7, 3.3 and also PyPy 2.0b1):

```
>>> import weakref
>>> x = set()
>>> y = weakref.proxy(x)
>>> x.__class__, isinstance(x, set), type(x)
(<type 'set'>, True, <type 'set'>)
>>> y.__class__, isinstance(y, set), type(y)
(<type 'set'>, True, <type 'weakproxy'>)
```

we'll see that `y.__class__` corresponds to the wrapped type for `weakref.proxy` (I suppose that `weakref.proxy` just replaces the attribute for disguise). Even `isinstance` identifies `y` as `set`.

But `type` shows the "true" type -- `weakproxy`. So, `type` doesn't use `__class__` attribute to identify an argument's type, does it? Does it use some "more reliable" source for this purpose? If so, can we access it directly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`x.__class__` and `type(x)` are not equivalent.
`type(x)` is rooted in [typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L2362), and will return the true type `ob_type`.

> /* Special case: type(x) should return x->ob_type */

While `x.__class__` is just an attribute lookup. It is equivalent to `object.__getattribute__(x, '__class__')`, unless the attribute lookup has been redefined.
`object`'s `'__class__'` is a data descriptor, which is also defined in [typeobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3998). Its [getter](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3813) returns `ob_type` as well. Thus, in most cases, `x.__class__` and `type(x)` return the same thing.

But `weakproxy`, namely `_PyWeakref_ProxyType`, deliberately defined its own [`proxy_getattr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/weakrefobject.c#L684). That's why `y.__class__` is not the same as `type(y)` in your case.

In the following experiment, we can achieve the same effect.

```
class A(object):
    pass

class C(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == '__class__':
            return A
        return object.__getattribute__(self, name)


>>> c = C()
>>> c.__class__
<class '__main__.A'>
>>> type(c)
<class '__main__.C'>
```

Moreover, `isinstance(c, A)` and `isinstance(c, C)` are both true in this example. Since `isinstance` would check the equality of `ob_type` first.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

About `isinstance`. Does it firstly check `ob_type` and then, if it isn't equals, `__class__`?

Comment: @IvanYurchenko, roughly, yes, first `ob_type`, then `__class__`. Actually, there is a special hook, [`__instancecheck__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__instancecheck__#class.__instancecheck__), between them.